# Having trouble applying sorting to this program

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sorting, multidimensional-array

The goal of the program is to generate a multidimensional array, of variable size, the  number of columns being the numbers of political parties, the number of rows being the "round" we're in, and the entries of the first row being the number of votes each political party got, then as you get into the second row, round 2, you divide all the values in the first row by 2, in round 3 you divide the values in the first row by 3, and the same thing goes for how many rows the thing has.
I got all that done, but after those operations are over, I want to be able to find the N largest elements, n being the number of rows, and place those elements in a vector, for some reason I can't seem to find, when I run it nothing is displayed on the console, when I get to the part where I want it to sort out the elements, it blacks out, and then crashes.

I've tried changing things around, I don't really think the problem is in the algorithm itself, as I've tried it with static arrays that I've filled randomly, and it sorted those out just fine. Like I said I don't really know where the problem is so I'll show a large part, I've cut out everything not pertinent.

```
 double** ELEITORAL;
 void bubble_sort(double** ELEITORAL)
    {
        int x, y;
        double tItem;
        int PassCount;
        bool Mudou;
for (PassCount = 0; PassCount < (MAX_rows * MAX_columns); PassCount++)       
{
        //orders the rows
        for (y = 0; y < MAX_columns; y++)
         {
            Mudou = true;
            while (Mudou)
            {
            Mudou = false;
        for (x = 1; x < MAX_rows; x++)
            {
            if (ELEITORAL[x - 1][y] > ELEITORAL[x][y])
                {
                Mudou = true;
                tItem = ELEITORAL[x - 1][y];
                ELEITORAL[x - 1][y] = ELEITORAL[x][y];
                ELEITORAL[x][y] = tItem;

                }
            }
        }
}
        //ORDERS THE COLUMNS 
        for (x = 0; x < MAX_rows; x++)
        {
            Mudou = true;
            while (Mudou)
                {
                Mudou = false;
                for (y = 1; y < MAX_columns; y++)
                {
                if (ELEITORAL[x][y - 1] > ELEITORAL[x][y])
                    {
                        Mudou = true; 
                    tItem = ELEITORAL[x][y - 1];
                    ELEITORAL[x][y - 1] = ELEITORAL[x][y];
                    ELEITORAL[x][y] = tItem; 
                    cout << "entrei";
                    system("pause");
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void DisplayTheArray(double** ELEITORAL)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < MAX_columns; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < MAX_rows; x++)
            {
                cout.width(5);
                cout << ELEITORAL[x][y];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
void fill(double **p, int rowsize, int colsize) {

      std::cout << std::fixed;
      std::cout << std::setprecision(1);
 printf("\n  Introduza o n%cmero de votos nas listas por ordem \n", 163);
    for (int col = 0; col < colsize; col++)
        {
         cin >> p[row][col];
        }
    cout << endl; 
    for (int row = 1; row < rowsize; row++)  
        {                                               
        for (int col = 0; col < colsize; col++) 
                {
                    p[row][col] = (p[0][col]/(row + 1));
                }
                cout << endl; //preenche as linhas 
            }
    }//FILL OUT THE ARRAY

   void print(double **p, int rowsize, int colsize) 
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < header.size(); i++) { //HEADER IS TO STORE THE 
           //NAMES OF THE POLITICAL PARTIES
            cout << setw(9) << header[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        for (row = 0; row < rowsize; row++) //IMPRIME A MATRIZ EM SI
        {
            for (col = 0; col < colsize; col++)
               {
                   cout << setw(10) << p[row][col];

               }
            cout << endl;

     }
   }//PRINTS THE ARRAY

    int MATRIZ()
    {
        std::cout << std::fixed;
        std::cout << std::setprecision(1);
        double rows, columns;
        printf("\n Qual o n%cmero de candidatos a eleger? \n", 163);
        cin >> rows;
        printf("\n Qual o n%cmero de listas candidatas? \n", 163);
        cin >> columns;
        for (i = 0; i < columns; i++)
            {
                cout << " Qual o nome da lista " << i+1;
                cout << endl;
                cin >> nomL;
                header.push_back(nomL);
            }
        cout << endl;
        system("cls");
        ELEITORAL = new double*[rows];
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
         {
            ELEITORAL[row] = new double[columns];
         }
         fill(ELEITORAL, rows, columns);
         cout << endl;
         //After this I have a switch, in case 5 I call the functions 
         //giving me trouble
case '5':
        {
            bubble_sort(ELEITORAL);
            DisplayTheArray(ELEITORAL);
            break;
        }
```

Comment: "I tried changing things aroung" - trust me, C++ is *not* a language you program with like cooking spaghetti. You don't just throw something at the wall and see if it sticks. Even if it appears to "work", there's no guarantee it is *correct*. (and there *is* a significant difference).  This has no `main()` and is missing several important apparent constants. Ex: in `fill` you have `cin >> p[row][col];` in a loop. Dare I ask wher `row` is coming from ?

Comment: It has a main, I didn't add it because I didn't want to  show even more code, its mostly just a call to a bunch of diferent menus

Comment: I understand, and the deal there is you must reduce your code to the problem at hand, including providing the data needed to trigger the problem. Another potential problem, btw, is your sort always tapping max row and column dimensions vs the *actual* row and column dimensions of your input data. Unless they match, you're basically sorting junk and/or accessing indeterminate and/or non-existent pointers. Every function that takes a `double** ELEITORAL` argument should also take the row/column dimensions as well. It makes zero sense to do otherwise.

Comment: @ChuckNorris FYI -- Once you learn modern C++, the program could look something [like this](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/783ad5e1e5d18fb4).

Answer (score 1):

Your display function is sketchy as you assume that the array has MAX dimensions. So my bet would be that your program seg faults due to memory access violation. Please, don't use `new`, instead use a `vector`. You won't have to pass the length as a separate parameter and in this case you won't get it wrong. Also double is not appropriate type for indexing, turn on compiler warnings and fix them.

Here's a simple example how can `vector` be used to make a matrix:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


using row_t = std::vector<double>;
using matrix_t = std::vector<row_t>;
//matrix_t = std::vector<std::vector<double>>;  Vector of vectors of double


//Pass by reference to avoid copy
//Pass by const if the matrix should be read-only
void printMatrix(const matrix_t& mat)
{
    for(auto& row: mat)
        for(auto& val: row)
            std::cout<<val << ' ';
        std::cout<<'\n';//Use this instead of endl if you want just a new line
}

void doubleMatrix(matrix_t& mat)
{
    //If you need access to indices during iterating
    for(std::size_t r = 0; r < mat.size();++r)
        for(std::size_t c = 0; c < mat[r].size();++r)
            mat[r][c] *=2.0;
}
int main()
{
    std::size_t rows, columns;

    std::cin >> rows;
    std::cin >> columns;

    double fill_value = 0.0;

    matrix_t matrix(rows);
    //Resize rows to given column width.
    for(auto& row: matrix)
        row.resize(columns, fill_value);

    printMatrix(matrix);
    doubleMatrix(matrix);
    printMatrix(matrix);
}
```

Last thing I noticed, If you want to swap two values, use `std::swap`.

Comment: How would I go about using vectors to create a matrice like this one?

Comment: @ChuckNorris Give me a sec, I will make a small example.

Comment: @ChuckNorris There.